# POST multiple Node clones to array of objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have a mongodb model that looks like this:

```
ingredients: [
  quantity: Number,
  measurement: String,
  name: String
]
```

These are being passed in with a single form where the user can add new ingredients by clicking a button which clones the input node and appends it to the parent node. So currently all of the name='' values are the same. As it is now, this is passing in a single array like this:

```
ingredients: [{
  quantity: ['1','2','3'],
  measurement: ['cup','tsp','tbsp'],
  name: ['rice','cumin','pepper']
}]
```

Right now the form input is declaring name like name='recipe[ingredients][quantity]' (recipe is the parent object). How do I make this pass multiple objects into the ingredients string?

Relevent section of form:

```
div class='add-ingredient-form'>
              <input type='text' name='recipe.ingredients[quantity]' placeholder='1' class='form-control' style='width: 10%; display: inline-block;'></input>
              <select class='form-control' style='width: 15%; display: inline-block;' name='recipe.ingredients[measurement]'>
                <option>#</option>
                <option>tsp</option>
                <option>tbsp</option>
                <option>cup</option>
                <option>lb</option>
                <option>fl oz</option>
              </select>
              <input type='text' name='recipe.ingredients[name]' placeholder='Carrots' class='form-control' style='width: 60%; display: inline-block;'></input>
              <a class='btn btn-md btn-danger delete-ingredient-button' href='#' onclick='deleteIngredient(this)'><i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
            </div>
```

How recipe is being created on route:

```
Recipe.create(req.body.recipe, function(err, newRecipe) {}
```

Comment: `this is passing` - what is this? some of your code? some mongo thing? aliens from the planet tharg?

Comment: "Clicking a button" is not a back end action. Which are you asking? A. How to have multiple options submitted from my 'front end' form? B. How to add input I receive from the form to the existing document arrays or overwrite them? Because those are two different questions.

Comment: @NeilLunn it is a submit button on a form so yes it is communicating with the back end

Comment: @JaromandaX I just mean that is the format of the array that the back end route is receiving. That's what shows up when it is console.logged

Comment: Dude. You were asked a A or B question. You have nodejs and mongodb tags on the question but "clicking a button" has nothing to do with either. So again, "which question are you asking?" A. Form submission stuff; or B. Database writing stuff. At any rate your question needs fixing from it's current content to clarify what you are even asking then, but "first up" let's just direct you to the right audience for answers.

Comment: `the back end route is receiving` - from where? you should show some *relevant* code, makes things easier

Comment: You probably need to have the first input name as `recipe[ingredients][0][quantity]`. When you clone you change name for the cloned to `recipe[ingredients][1][quantity]` and keep incrementing as you go

Comment: @OluwafemiSule that would definitely work, but I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: @JaromandaX updated

Answer (score 0):

Name inputs with ingredients as an array in this format `recipe.ingredients[][name]`.

When the form is submitted to the server, the request body will contain the form data in this form:

```
recipe {
  ingredients: [
    { quantity: Number, measurement: String, name: String },
    { quantity: Number, measurement: String, name: String },
  ]
}
```

#### Example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#more_btn').on('click', function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     $entries = $('.add-ingredient-form');
     $entry = $entries.last();
     var clone = $entry.clone();
     var namePrefix = 'recipe.ingredients[';
     clone.find('input,select').each(function (i, el){
       el.value = '';
     });
     $entry.append(clone);
  });

  $('#submit_btn').on('click', function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     var form = $('#ingredient-form').serializeArray();
     console.log(form);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="ingredient-form">
  <div class='add-ingredient-form'>
    <input type='text' name='recipe.ingredients[][quantity]' placeholder='1' class='form-control' style='width: 10%; display: inline-block;' />
    <select class='form-control' style='width: 15%; display: inline-block;' name='recipe.ingredients[][measurement]'>
    <option>#</option>
    <option>tsp</option>
    <option>tbsp</option>
    <option>cup</option>
    <option>lb</option>
    <option>fl oz</option>
  </select>
    <input type='text' name='recipe.ingredients[][name]' placeholder='Carrots' class='form-control' style='width: 60%; display: inline-block;' />
    <a class='btn btn-md btn-danger delete-ingredient-button' href='#' onclick='deleteIngredient(this)'><i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
  </div>
  <button id="more_btn">Add Ingredient</button>
  <button id="submit_btn">Submit Form</button>
</form>
```

#### Note that:

cloned `.add-ingredient-form` may need to reset values of form controls to a default.